# Tkinter.self causing infinite loop with error

Tags: python, tkinter, infinite-loop

**The following program gives an error message:**

> "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object".

The cause is the `self.after`.

It works fine when I create a `while true` loop in the Calculation function, but I would like to cause the loop with a `self.after`, which is how I read it should be done in connection with *Tkinter*. Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import time

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=tk.Tk()
        self.var1=tk.StringVar()
        self.i=0

    def Calculation(self):
        # complex calculations that last 30 minutes in total
        self.i+=1
        self.var1.set(str(self.i))
        self.root.update()
        self.after(100, self.Calculation)

    def Gui(self):
        your_label=tk.Label(self.root,textvariable=self.var1).pack()

A=App()
A.Gui()
A.Calculation()
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Each calculation starts another calculation every 100 milliseconds, and these kick off further calculations, etc.  This can't be what you want.

Comment: It's a Monte Carlo simulation. So each calculation needs to be done many times, but since they last for a while, I need an update in my gui after each round of calculations. Also I would like to be able to change some parameters during the calculation, ideally with a slider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recursion is being caused by your `App` class being derived from `tk.TK` rather than `tk.Frame`. On top of that, your `__init__()` method creates a second instance of its own base class with the `self.root=tk.Tk()` statement instead of calling its base class's `__init__()` method as it should. This is especially troublesome in this case because an instance of the `tk.TK` class is the `Toplevel` widget of Tk which contains the Tcl interpreter and there generally should only ever be one of them in existence.

Here's something that changes the base class and accomplishes what I think you're trying to do in the proper manner. In it I've corrected, modified, and simplified a number other things, notably making the code conform to the [PEP8 style guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.var1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.i = 0
        tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var1).pack()

    def calculation(self):
        # complex calculations that last 30 minutes in total
        self.i += 1
        self.var1.set(str(self.i))
#        self.update()  # no need, will be automatic as mainloop() runs
        self.after(100, self.calculation)

app=App()
app.calculation()  # start calculations
app.mainloop()  # run gui
```

Comment: The comment "# automatic due to Label's use of textvariable" is incorrect. Calling update is unnecessary because `mainloop` is running, not because you are using `textvariable`. When your function ends, the event loop is re-entered.

Comment: @Bryan: Thanks for setting things straight.

Comment: That works the way I would like it, but why does it stop working when I add time.sleep(1) after self.i += 1?

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little bit of a rewrite by getting rid of the separate Gui function but I think this should do what you want it to do.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import time

class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.i = 0
        self.label = tk.Label(text=str(self.i))
        self.label.pack()
        self.calculation()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def calculation(self):
        self.i = self.i + 1
        self.label.configure(text=self.i)
        self.root.after(100, self.calculation)

app=App()
```